# How to make tipa compatible with braket?

Tags: incompatibility, tipa, braket

The following minimal working example generates an error if you remove the per cent sign.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\[
\Set{x|y}
\]
\end{document}
```

The error message:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \: invalid in math mode on input line 6.
LaTeX Warning: Command \: invalid in math mode on input line 6.
LaTeX Warning: Command \; invalid in math mode on input line 6.
LaTeX Warning: Command \; invalid in math mode on input line 6.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.6 \Set{x|y}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `tipa` package redefines some standard commands and this is the cause for the errors you get, but provides a “compatibility” layer. Notably the command it redefines are

- `\s` (alias `\textsyllabic`)
- `\*` (no alias provided)
- `\|` (no alias provided)
- `\:` (alias `\tipamedspace`)
- `\;` (alias `\tipathickspace`)
- `\!` (alias `\tipanegthinspace`)

If you call the package with the `safe` option, that is,

```
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
```

the redefinitions are not performed. Section 3.1.3 of the `tipa` manual.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in `braket.sty` there is:

```tex
{\catcode`\|=\active
  \xdef\set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname set \endcsname#1{\mathinner
        {\lbrace\,{\mathcode`\|32768\let|\midvert #1}\,\rbrace}}
  \xdef\Set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Set \endcsname#1{\left\{%
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\fi
     \:{\let\|\SetDoubleVert
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\SetVert
     #1}\:\right\}}
}
\def\midvert{\egroup\mid\bgroup}
\def\SetVert{\@ifnextchar|{\|\@gobble}% turn || into \|
    {\egroup\;\mid@vertical\;\bgroup}}
\def\SetDoubleVert{\egroup\;\mid@dblvertical\;\bgroup}
```

The detail what the code does exactly is not important, however note that `\:` and `\;` is used in the code. If `tipa` redefines these commands, of course there will be problems.

One way is to redefine these macros in `braket.sty`.

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{braket}


\makeatletter
{\catcode`\|=\active
  \xdef\set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname set \endcsname#1{\mathinner
        {\lbrace\,{\mathcode`\|32768\let|\midvert #1}\,\rbrace}}
  \xdef\Set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Set \endcsname#1{\left\{%
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\fi
     \medspace{\let\|\SetDoubleVert
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\SetVert
     #1}\medspace\right\}}
}
\def\midvert{\egroup\mid\bgroup}
\def\SetVert{\@ifnextchar|{\|\@gobble}% turn || into \|
    {\egroup\thickspace\mid@vertical\thickspace\bgroup}}
\def\SetDoubleVert{\egroup\thickspace\mid@dblvertical\thickspace\bgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\Set{x|y}
\]
\end{document}
```

Another way is to use `\tipasafemode` every time you need `\Set`, as suggested in `tipa` documentation (this is obviously clunky).

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
{\tipasafemode
\[
\Set{x|y}
\]
}
\end{document}
```